# CURL working from localhost but not on live site

Tags: php, curl

I have a CURL code that fetches some XML content from a remote server. I get the expected output on my localhost (XAMPP on windows). But from the live site(hosted on Linux), I get the CURL error:'couldn't connect to host'.

```
 function DownloadUrl($Url, $p){
```

// is curl installed?
  if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
   die('CURL is not installed!');
  }

```
   // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

if($output === false)
 echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
else
  print $output;
    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to ping your host from the linux server ? Have you tried to wget your host from your linux server ? If yes, was the result ok ?

Comment: this should be tagged PHP also.

Comment: It would be useful to know what your remote environment is too, i.e Shared Hosting, VPS etc. Some Shared providers won't allow you to pull in content from other sites using curl. If you're on a VPS you might want to check that there are appropriate iptables rules to allow you outbound connections too.

Answer (score 1):

On you live server. run `phpinfo();` and check to make sure php_curl is installed and active. This normally throws a fatal exception however rather than the "could not connect to host." message you are getting.

If you are still having problems, you may want to try a traceroute to teh URL through SSH to make sure the website can actually connect. There may be a configuration setting or other service that is causing issues.